# Laravel - can't access an object property

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following code:

```
$items = Item::where('type','egg')
        ->select('id','name','image','description')
        ->with('craft.reqItem')->get();

foreach($items as $item) {
            if (sizeof($item->craft)) {
                foreach ($item->craft as $craftItem)
                    return $craftItem;
            }
        }
```

The output is the following JSON:

[image]

When I'm trying to access the req_item from the code, laravel outputs nothing. 
I'm trying to do it by changing:

`return $craftItem` to:

`return $craftItem->req_item`

If I'm trying to output any other property other than req_item (such as id,item_id,quantity) - laravel do return the right value.

Any idea why I can't access the `req_item` object?

dd req_item

[image]

Comment: Can you write ` dd($craftItem); ` and paste the output here?

Comment: can you try a `dump($craftItem->req_item);` before the return line please ?

Comment: @Frondor updated question with screenshot of dd

Comment: I assume you want to call this object through relationship? Relationships are generally camelCased. Could you show us your relationship?

Comment: Updated with the relationship code @devk

Comment: Try calling like this: `$craftItem->reqItem`. Should work like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's it, `$craftItem->reqItem` is an object and you can't simply "output" an object.

But you can do something like `$craftItem->reqItem->req_item_id` (that in the case you eager loaded `reqItem`, assuming its a relationship).

If that's not the case, then you simply call the query like `$craftItem->reqItem()->req_item_id`

Although I'd prefer eager loading, which probably you'll want to read about in the docs... But just to test your example is working, you can do something like `$item->load('reqItem')` before the conditional statement. And then you can access it as a property.

As devk mentioned, relationships have to be camelCase named. You may want to change it to `reqItem()` for simplicity.

Comment: I tried, I get `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: @TheUnreal is `req_item` a relationship?

Comment: @TheUnreal Alright, just edited my reply with more info

Comment: Hey @fronder, Thanks! is there any way to add a new property to the relationship items using foreach?

Comment: @TheUnreal I'm not sure if I get your point but in that case, you should be able to do something like `$craftItem->reqItem->newAttribute` if you eager loaded the relationship. If that doesn't work, try overwriting it (not recommended) like `$craftItem->setRelation('reqItem', $modifiedRelation)` and that `$modifiedRelation` has the new attributes. That's not the best way of course, but its something I'd try for sure

Answer (score -2):

try $craftItem->reqItem['req_item_id'] ,might work